# Apache Ignite: "Failed to do service reassignment" on server stop with singleton service

Tags: java, ignite

I have Ignite cluster with 2 server nodes and singleton service deployed on it.

If I first stop node which currently runs service, and then (with particular delay, about ~ 100 ms) second one, I'm getting

```
ERROR o.a.i.i.p.s.GridServiceProcessor - Failed to do service reassignment (will retry): statService
org.apache.ignite.internal.IgniteInterruptedCheckedException: Got interrupted while waiting for future to complete.
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.util.future.GridFutureAdapter.get0(GridFutureAdapter.java:185)
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.util.future.GridFutureAdapter.get(GridFutureAdapter.java:140)
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.processors.service.GridServiceProcessor$TopologyListener$1.run0(GridServiceProcessor.java:1810)
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.processors.service.GridServiceProcessor$DepRunnable.run(GridServiceProcessor.java:2027)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
```

I guess, second server sees another server is down, so it wants to start service. Then at unlucky moment this server stops, and `ExecutorService depExe` at `GridServiceProcessor` get interrupted, so exception occurs. But Ignite knows if it stopping, so I'm sure Ignite could expect interrupts, or take care of it in some way.

So how could I avoid this error?

Ignite version: 2.5.2

Answer (score 0):

You have 2 nodes and you stop both of them? What behaviour do you expect in this case?

This exception is harmless. I think, it deserves DEBUG log level.
Feel free to file a [JIRA](https://issues.apache.org/jira/issues/) ticket and fix it.